# VBA- Change X values of Pie Chart to a range in a non-active worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

This should be very easy, but I can't figure out the syntax.  I want to change the X values of the PieChart to be equal to whatever is in the range of B8:B12. This is my code for setting up a PieChart.

```
Set pie_chart = Charts.Add()
With pie_chart
    .ChartType = xlPie
    .SetSourceData Source:=new_sheet.Range("C2:C" & _
        num_bins + 1), _
        PlotBy:=xlColumns
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, _
        Name:=new_sheet.Name
End With

With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = title
    .ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlDataLabelsShowLabelAndPercent, LegendKey _
    :=False, HasLeaderLines:=True
    .SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Content!$B$8:$B$12"
End With
```

The line in question that needs to be changed is `.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "Content!$B$8:$B$12"`, because the code generates a great deal of Worksheets, not all of which are named Content.  Instead, I need it to grab the X-values from B8-B12 of whatever the name of worksheet is that the chart resides on.

If it helps, the name of the Parent Sheet of the Chart is saved in the variable `new_sheet`

I tried things like `.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues="new_sheet.Name!$B$8:$B$12"` and `.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues=new_sheet.Name&"!$B$8:$B$12"`

I'm not sure why this wouldn't work:  `.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & new_sheet.Name & "!$B$8:$B$12"`

Comment: Try `.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & new_sheet.Name & "'!$B$8:$B$12"`?  Yours might fail if there are spaces in the sheet.name.

Comment: That works!  If you want to put that as the answer, I'll check it up for you.  Why does this work?

Comment: Done, with explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & new_sheet.Name & "'!$B$8:$B$12"`

If there are any spaces in the sheet's `.Name`, your previous attempt will construct a malformed formula, which will cause an error, e.g.:

`=My Worksheet!A1:B1` is an invalid reference which will result in a `#Name?` error.  When a worksheet name contains spaces, you need to enclose the name in single quotes.  So, rather than try and figure out when this is needed, just always use the single quotes to avoid this error.

Comment: David- do you know why this doesn't work for Mac 2011? "Method or Data Member not Found."

Comment: Maybe I have a typo. Try `.SeriesCollection(1)` I am not sure why I would have said `.FullSeriesCollection(...` because that is certainly not a method or property of a chart.

Comment: Well, it is, actually.  It's recognized by Excel 2013, just not Excel 2010 for Macs.

Comment: Ahhh well I don't have access to either of Excel 2013, or any version of Excel for Mac.  What is `new_sheet`?, I don't see it defined anywhere in your example code.  In any case, it doesn't seem to have an `XValues` property.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj230578.aspx

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't mention it in the earliest post, but your modification to remove the word "Full", worked well! Thanks.